# Retain Listview scroll on page navigation

Tags: listview, windows-8, microsoft-metro, vertical-scrolling

How can I maintain the `listview` `scroll position` if I navigate away to another page and come back by pressing `back` button?

It always `resets it to top`. Its a real pain to go back to the poition I was. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly Step 1 will do the trick, If not you have to make changes in your listView by following step 2

1) `this.NavigationCacheMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;`

2)

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can add NavigationCacheMode="Enabled" in your Page XAML:

```
<Page 
NavigationCacheMode="Enabled">
```

Comment: I tried caching the page but caching the page retains its state forever, what if I am navigating forward from my homepage to this cached page, in that situation I want to be at top. How do I achieve that